# Frac$(R/p)=(R/p)_p$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

$R$ is a commutative ring with unity and $p$ is a prime ideal.

Then Frac$(R/p)=(R/p)_p$?

Both Frac$(R/p)$ and $(R/p)_p$ contain $R/p$ but how do we know $(R/p)_p$ is the smallest field containing $R/p$? I guess the canonical homomorphism is the isomorphism between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple: passing from $\;R/\mathfrak p\;$ to $\;(R/\mathfrak p)_{\mathfrak p}\simeq R_{\mathfrak p}\big/\mathfrak pR_{\mathfrak p}\;$ consists in making invertible the nonzero congruence classes in  $R/\mathfrak p$. Isn't that the fraction field of $R/\mathfrak p\mkern1mu$?

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes, that sounds obvious and I thought I needed to check the isomorphism, Frac$(R/p)\cong (R/p)_p$ which looks trivial again.

Comment: Maybe a thing you didn't perceive very well is that introducing denominators from $R-\mathfrak p$ (as an $R$-modules) is the same as introducing denominators from $(R/\mathfrak p)^*$  (as an $R/\mathfrak p$-module).